# how to create a entry box that understands key words in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How do i make the netry box pick out a key word from array x (e.g. if
 i type "my screen isnt working", it would look through array x to find
 the keyword 'screen' and give the response "is your screen cracked")?

> ```
> from tkinter import *
>
> from tkinter import messagebox
>
> x = ['screen','speakers','earphone jack','button','battery','storage']
>
> y = ['is the screen cracked','have the speakers been in conatct with
> water','has the earphone jack been in contact with water','is your
> button broken','is your battery older than 2 years','is the storage
> you have less than the required']
>
> z = ['change your screen','put your phone in uncooked rice overnight
> and check in the morning','put your phone in uncooked rice overnight
> and check in the morning','go to a phone store and buy a new
> button','change your phone battery','delete data to have enough
> storage space for you to download whatever you need']
>
> def problem1_1():
>
> i =  ' '.join(x)
>
> i.split(' ')
>
> p = problem1.get().lower()
>
> if p in x:
>
>     questions =  messagebox.askyesno(title = "question", message =y[x.index(p)])
>
>     if questions == True:
>
>         messagebox.showinfo(title =" solution", message = z[x.index(p)])
>
>     else:
>
>         messagebox.showinfo(title =" solution", message = "go to the nearest phone repair store and recieve direct help")
>
> else:
>
>     messagebox.showinfo(title = "ERROR",message ="Please enter a valid category of issue you have")
>
> return
> myGui = Tk()
>
> problem1 = StringVar()
>
> myGui.geometry("500x500+200+200")
> #this makes the size and positioning of the page GUI
>
> myGui.title("troubleshooting system")
> #this makes the title at the top of the page GUI
>
> myheader1 = Label(text = "Welcome To the Phone Troubleshooting
> System",font = ("weight bold",16)).pack()
> #This creates a header at the top-centre of the page GUI
>
> header2 = Label(text = '''What seems to be the issue with  your phone?
> Is it an issue with your : screen, speakers, button,earphone jack,
> battery or storage''',fg = 'blue',bg = 'yellow', font =("weight bold",
>   16) ).pack()
>
> ientry = Entry(textvariable = problem1).pack()
>
> OkButton = Button(text = 'OK', command = problem1_1).pack()
>
> myGui.mainloop()
> #This closes the Tkinter function and runs it
> ```

Comment: please fix the formatting of your question. As written it's impossible to read.

Comment: don't do `var = Widget().pack()`. It assigns `None` to `var` because `pack()` returns `None`. Do it in two steps `var = Widget()` and `var.pack()`

Comment: what is the problem. Your code works for me.

Comment: @furas the problem is it works when you put in "screen", however when you put in a sentence it says that the answer isn't valid. how do i do it so that it can take out key words from a whole sentence

Comment: `split()` sentence into list of words and check all words - one by one - using `for` loop.

Comment: Or `for word in x: if word in sentence: do_something`

Comment: @furas i tried this but it didnt work:
def problem1_1():
    i =  ' '.join(x)
    j = i.split(' ')
    p = problem1.get().lower()
    for j in x:
        if j in p: 
            questions =  messagebox.askyesno(title = "question", message =y[x.index(p)])
            if questions == True://////////////////////////////////////
and the rest is the same however this didn't work. im quite new to tkinter so maybe my logic is wrong. please tell me what i can change to make this better

Comment: always add code (error messages and other long information) in question - it will be more readable than in comment.

Comment: There's a lot of code on the question that isn't relevant. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop to check every `keyword` in sentence

```
for word in x:
    if word in p:
       do_something()
```

Using better names for variables:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

# --- data ---

keywords = [
    'screen',
    'speakers',
    'earphone jack',
    'button',
    'battery',
    'storage'
]

questions = [
    'is the screen cracked',
    'have the speakers been in conatct with water',
    'has the earphone jack been in contact with water',
    'is your button broken',
    'is your battery older than 2 years',
    'is the storage you have less than the required'
]

solutions = [
    'change your screen',
    'put your phone in uncooked rice overnight and check in the morning',
    'put your phone in uncooked rice overnight and check in the morning',
    'go to a phone store and buy a new button',
    'change your phone battery',
    'delete data to have enough storage space for you to download whatever you need'
]

# --- functions ---

def problem1_1():

    sentence = problem1.get().lower()

    for idx, word in enumerate(keywords):

        if word in sentence:

            yes = messagebox.askyesno(title="question", message=questions[idx])

            if yes:
                msg = solutions[idx]
            else:
                msg = "go to the nearest phone repair store and recieve direct help"

            messagebox.showinfo(title="solution", message=msg)

            break # found keyword in sentence

    else: # no break - so it doesn't found any keyword in sentence
        messagebox.showinfo(title="ERROR", message="Please enter a valid category of issue you have")

# --- main ---

myGui = Tk()

problem1 = StringVar()

myGui.geometry("500x500+200+200")

myGui.title("troubleshooting system")

Label(text="Welcome To the Phone Troubleshooting System", font=("weight bold", 16)).pack()

Label(text='''What seems to be the issue with  your phone?
Is it an issue with your: screen, speakers, button, earphone jack,
battery or storage''', fg='blue', bg='yellow', font=("weight bold", 16)).pack()

Entry(textvariable=problem1).pack()

Button(text='OK', command=problem1_1).pack()

myGui.mainloop()
```

BTW: there is `for/break/else` construction, not `if/else` - so `else` has the same indention as `for`.